# Get data by socket.io in html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I have read a lot of tutorial, and sample code to send data from a node.js class to an html page and show this data.
such as [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914816/what-is-an-example-of-the-simplest-possible-socket-io-example), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545153/transfer-udp-socket-in-node-js-from-application-to-http),[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190028/node-js-listen-for-udp-and-forward-to-connected-http-web-clients),[link4](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/getting-started-with-socket-io-adding-real-time-events-to-your-node-js-express-app.html),[link5](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/)
 and some others.

I am getting some data from UDP listener and need to send it after some processing to an html page to show it. here is my code:

The udp receiver:

```
    var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

var http = require('http'),
    dgram = require('dgram'),
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    fs = require('fs');

var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/html/showMap.html');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-type': 'text/html'
  });
  res.end(html);
  io.sockets.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!'});

}).listen( server_port, server_ip_address, function() {
  console.log('Listening');
});

var io = socketio.listen(app),
    socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

socket.on('message', function(content, rinfo) {
    console.log('got message', content, 'from', rinfo.address, rinfo.port);
    io.sockets.emit('udp message', 'content' /*content.toString()*/);
});

socket.bind(5001);
```

and my html page which is called 'showMap.html'

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Get Data</title>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results">    This text will change     </div>
    <div id="date">sample another temp text</div>
    <script>
    // client code here
    var socket = io.connect('localhost', {port: 8080});
    socket.on('udp message', function(message) {
      console.log(message)
      document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "My new text!";​
  });
  socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data.message;
  });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but by sending packet, html page has not changed.
Here is my console log of running code:

> Atis-MacBook-Pro:startWithNode muser$ npm start
>
> > StartWithNodejs@1.0.0 start /Volumes/Project/Project/NodeJS/startWithNode
> >     node index.js
>
> Listening got message  from 127.0.0.1 64047

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: If more information is needed, I am ready to share

Comment: Hi. Rather than `io.connect('localhost', {port: 8080});` try `io.connect('127.0.0.1:8080');`

Comment: @dan the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this locally. In your HTML file I made two changes and it worked.

1 - Replace `io.connect('localhost', {port: 8080});` with `io.connect('localhost:8080');`

2 - There was a strange \u200b character at the end of the `document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "My new text!";` line. I deleted that and ended up with:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Get Data</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div id="results">    This text will change     </div>
      <div id="date">sample another temp text</div>
    <script>
      // client code here
      var socket = io.connect('localhost:8080');
      socket.on('udp message', function(message) {
      console.log(message)
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "My new text!";
      });
      socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data.message;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which replaces the content of `results`.

Comment: thank you, I spent a lot of time and this html works

Comment: @Fa.Shapouri no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

in this example you will be able to get JSON data from php file and send it to all connected clients.

RunThisFileThroughNodeJs.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var request = require("request")
var url = "http://localhost/api/index.php";
events = require('events'),
    serverEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){


    setInterval(
        function(){

            request({
                url: url,
                json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {

                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    io.emit('chat message', body);
                }
            });
        },5000);




});


http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Don't Forget to install express , request for nodejs

Now make this file i will call it index.html so the response of my file will be here.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prices API</title>
  <script src="http://localhost/js/socket.io.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="price_list"></div>
<script>
   var socket = io();
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){

    document.getElementById("price_list").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(msg);

    console.log(msg);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```